# Trying to get the direction printed continuosly until another key is pressed

Tags: python, while-loop, pygame

I've made this game of snake (with the help of tutorials) and changed the arena's shape, I want to print the direction of the key pressed continuously until the snake changes direction, if that makes sense. My aim was from this to remake the snake's path so it would track the total movement of the snake at the end of your game (if you have any better ideas to do this please help). I thought that the "while" function would be good for this as a first step, however, it doesn't seem to work. If anyone could help that would be brilliant. All the Best.

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import threading
pygame.init()
from random import choice
blue = (0,0,255)
purple = (155, 0 , 155)
green = (0,225,200)
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
brown = (200, 180, 0)
dbrown = (180, 180, 0)
cream = (255, 255, 180)
screen = pygame.display.init()
dis_width = 840
dis_height = 640


dis=pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width,dis_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('patricks best attempt at making a snake game')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snake_block = 10
dis_bed = 200 - 240 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
snake_speed = 20

font_style = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
xchc= choice([i for i in range(1,840) if i not in [200,210,220,230,240]])
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 35)
def Your_score(score):
    value = score_font.render("your score" + str(score), True, black)
    dis.blit(value, [0,0])
def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis,blue, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])

def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    dis.blit(mesg, [dis_width/3, dis_height/2])





def gameLoop(): 
    game_over = False
    game_close = False

    x1 = 10
    y1 = dis_height -10

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0 

    snake_List = []
    Length_of_snake = 1

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0,dis_width - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(80, 640 - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
    while not game_over:


        while game_close == True:
            dis.fill(white)
            message("You lost q to quit, c to play", red)
            Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over=True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                    while event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        print("Left")
                        if event.key != pygame.K_LEFT:
                            break 
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                    print ("right")
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
                    print ("up")
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
                    print ("down")


        if x1 >= dis_width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= dis_height or y1 < 0:
            game_close = True

        elif 0 <= y1 and y1 <= 310 and 200 <= x1 and x1 <= 420:
            game_close = True
        elif 0 <= y1 and y1 <= 40 and 100 <= x1 and x1 <= 180:
            game_close = True
        elif 0 <= y1 and y1 <= 100 and 520 <= x1 and x1 <= 700:
            game_close = True
        elif 560 <= y1 and y1 <= 640 and 640 <= x1 and x1 <= 840:
            game_close = True
        elif 520 <= y1 and y1 <= 640 and 260 <= x1 and x1 <= 510:
            game_close = True




        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        dis.fill(cream)

        pygame.draw.rect(dis,black,[foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_List.append(snake_Head)
        if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_List[0]

        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True

        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)

        pygame.draw.rect(dis, blue, [x1, y1, snake_block, snake_block])
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, purple, [200,0,240,320])
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, brown, [100, 0, 80, 40])
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, dbrown, [520, 0, 180, 100])
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, brown, [640, 560, 200, 80])
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, dbrown, [260, 520, 260, 120])    
        pygame.display.update()

        if x1 == foodx and y1 ==foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0,dis_width - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(80, 640 - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1
        elif foodx in range(200,440) and foody in range(0,320):
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0,dis_width - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(80, 640 - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 0
        elif foodx in range(100, 180) and foody in range(0,40):
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0,dis_width - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(80, 640 - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 0
        elif foodx in range(520, 700) and foody in range(0,100):
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0,dis_width - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(80, 640 - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 0
        elif foodx in range(640, 840) and foody in range(560, 640):
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0,dis_width - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(80, 640 - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 0
        elif foodx in range(260, 520) and foody in range(520, 640):
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0,dis_width - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(80, 640 - snake_block)/10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 0

        clock.tick(snake_speed)




    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameLoop()
```

Comment: Please don't call it "`while` function".  `while` is keyword and it is used to declare a `while`-loop statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] I want to print the direction of the key pressed continuously until the snake changes direction [...]

You have to `print` the direction every time when the position.

Remove all the `print` instructions from the event loop:

```py
def gameLoop(): 
    # [...]

    while not game_over:
        # [...]

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over=True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                    print("Left")
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                    print ("right")
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
                    print ("up")
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
                    print ("down")
```

`print` the direction when `x1` respectively `y1` is changed:

```py
def gameLoop(): 
    # [...]

    while not game_over:
        # [...]

        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        if x1_change < 0:
            print("Left")
        elif x1_change > 0:
            print ("right")
        elif y1_change < 0:
           print ("up")
        elif y1_change < 0:
           print ("down")
```